# How to add a column wise row value in data table from for loop

Tags: c#

How to add  a row in the data table

Code

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Clear();
            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("day1", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            dc = new DataColumn("day2", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            dc = new DataColumn("day3", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

tString[0] = "Sat,mon,tue";
tString[1] = "Fri,,wed";
tString[2] = "Thu,";

 int lengthA = tString.Length;

 for (int i = 0; i <= lengthA - 1; i++)
            {
                string s = tString[i];

                    string[] words = s.Split(',');
                    foreach (string word in words)
                    {
                            dt.Rows.Add(word);
                    }

                }
```

The issue in dt.Rows.Add(word) because it is inserting a row

Expected Output

Datatable value should be

```
day1, day2, day3

sun,mon,tue
Fri,Wed
Thu
```

Hot to achieve this, can any one help me

Comment: Is the double comma between "Fri" and "wed" intentional or a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Just create a [NewRow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx) and then add the values to its [Item indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.item(v=vs.110).aspx) for each column.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= lengthA - 1; i++)
{
    string s = tString[i];
    string[] words = s.Split(',');
    // here is the new row
    var row = dt.NewRow(); 
    for(int w = 0; w < words.Length; w++)
    {
        // set each column
        row[w] = words[w];     
    }
    // don't forget to add the Row to the Rows collection
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```